# Beautiful URL mod-rewrite with only 1 exception, using apache htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite, folder-redirection

Dear All, trying to figure out this but no luck.
Want to rewrite and beautify this specific ...?ln=zh-CN to /cn/...
With the help of a genius @ StackOverflow(Laurence Gonsalves) im almost there! 
But stuck here:

**/it/somepage** goes nicely **/somepage?ln=it**
**/de/somepage** goes nicely **/somepage?ln=de**
**/fr/somepage** goes nicely **/somepage?ln=fr**
**/cn/somepage**   but this gives 404 error!
**/somepage?ln=zh-CN**  works ofcourse fine

```
# exception for Chinese version /cn/somepage
RewriteRule ^zh-CN/(.*) /$2?ln=zh-CN [L]
RewriteRule ^cn/(.*) /$2?ln=zh-CN [L]

# redirect all /XX/somepage goes to /somepage?ln=XX
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*) /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

The second part works perfectly! The first part doesnt do the work well for that one and only exception zh-CN...  What is being overlooked here? All clues or tips will be blessed with feminine attentions in our afterlife, i'm so sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read that right, replace `$2` in the first two rules with `$1`.

Explanation: You've only one set of brackets in the match, so the backreference `$2` is undefined (and will expand to an empty string, hence the 404), whereas `$1` will contain the text matched by `(.*)`

Comment: That was IT, now it works. Long live opensource communities. Also i now understand why it didnt work before. Thanks very much!